# How to make fullscreen an embedded Youtube video about jxbrowser in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, youtube-api, jxbrowser

I am working on a project in JavaFX with Netbeans. The project consists of emulating Youtube in a desktop application using the Youtube API. Right now I have a problem to make fullscreen of the video, I already get a video to play correctly, but I do not know how to do it fullscreeen, I'm using a library called jxbrowser to play the video. I have an HBox and inside a BrowserView, I need to press the fullscreen button on YouTube if the video is fullscreen but I have searched and I have not been able to do it, if anyone knows how I could do it or can give me any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, can you please post your code in the question? Since you are new I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching for a class, something like "ytp-fullscreen-button" and programmatically simulate a mouse click on it using JxBrowser DOM API.

The sample which demonstrates how to work with the DOM API can be viewed here: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013094-simulating-click

If you provide a sample code, it should shed more light on the issue.